# ¿Cual es este error que obtengo cuando uso socket.io?

Tags: nodejs, api, socket.io, angular

He creado un `API` que usa `socket.io`:

```
const socketIo = require('socket.io');
const serverHttps = https.createServer(httpsOptions, 
app).listen(httpsPort, () => { 
console.log('HTTPS: Server running at ' +  
httpsPort)});
const io = socketIo(serverHttps);
io.on('connection', (socket)=> { 
socket.emit('hello', { greeting: 'Hola 
George'}); 
 });
```

Y este `API` la consumo desde `Angular` donde tambien he implementado socket.io.

Cuando se inicia en el metodo `ngOnInit` para conectarse al `API` por medio de socket:

```
import * as socketIo from 'socket.io';
const socket = socketIo('https://192.168.120.201:8950');
```

Me tira este **error**

> WARNING in ./node_modules/socket.io/lib/index.js 
>   108:11-32 Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression

¿Alguna idea de lo que pueda ser?

¿Necesito instalar alguna otra libreria?

Comment: con esa captura de pantalla dime quien va a distinguir el error?

Comment: @JGuerra de preferencia que el codigo y el log con el error sea texto

Comment: puedes poner el código de la importación de socket.io-client, es muy probable que tu error sea por eso

Comment: Asi es como lo importo: import * as socketIo from 'socket.io';

Comment: Espero haber explicado mejor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para usar socket.io desde angular deberías usar socket.io-client

```
npm install --save socket.io-client
```

como buena practica deberías usarlo desde un servicio, y podrias usar observables para poder manejar los eventos "on" de socket.io un ejemplo de ello seria esto

```
// core
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

// socket.io
import * as io from 'socket.io-client';

// rxjs
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

@Injectable()
export class SocketService {

    socket: any;
    url:string = 'http://api.socket';
    constructor() { }

    connect(): void {
        this.socket = io.connect(this.url);
    }

    disconnect(): void {
        this.socket.disconnect();
    }

    isConnect(): boolean {
        if (this.socket) {
            return this.socket.connected;
        }
        return false
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param eventName
     */
    on(eventName: string): Observable<any> {
        return new Observable(observer => {
            if (this.socket) {
                this.socket.on(eventName, data => observer.next(data))
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param emitName
     * @param data
     */
    emit(emitName: string, data?: any) {
        if (this.socket) {
            this.socket.emit(emitName, data);
        }
    }

}
```

y ahora solo llamarías a connect desde el **ngOnInit()** del componente en que desees usarlo

Comment: aprovechando esta respuesta si quieres probar el socket server con un cliente websocket te recomiendo un plugins de chrome simple WebSocket Client